# Got compile error when trying to invoke function pointer to member functions

Tags: c++

I need to invoke member function by using function pointer to C++ member functions, but I got compile error

```
te5.cc:22:14: error: must use ‘.*’ or ‘->*’ to call pointer-to-member function in ‘fp (...)’, e.g. ‘(... ->* fp) (...)’
     b.*fp(100);
```

Here is the code snippet. Any idea how to make it work?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

class A {
public:
    void dum1(int a) { printf("A::dum1(%d)\n", a);}
    virtual void dum(int a) { printf("A::dum(%d)\n", a);};
};
class B : public A {
public:
    B() {
    }
    void dum(int a) { printf("B::dum(%d)\n", a);}
};
typedef void (A::*RUNFUNC)(int a);
RUNFUNC fp = &A::dum; //, &A::dum};

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    B b;
    b.*fp(100);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what's `a` actually?

Comment: it's just a integer. No special meaning.

Comment: What do you expect `RUNFUNC`does?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
b.*fp(100);
```

Wrong syntax, it should be (because `.*` has lower precedence than `()`)

```
(b.*fp)(100);
```

Answer (score 3):

Operator precedence requires you to put parentheses around the application of the pointer to member, and it's invocation. Like this:

```
(b.*fp)(100);
```

Otherwise, the it's parsed as `b.*(fp(100))`. [Silly, but those are the rules](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

Comment: thanks. Can't believe I missed something so silly :-)